# ssl blocking a javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, mixed-content

I have a webpage up and hosted. I have used 'pretty photo' plugin to play youtube videos on popups. It seems to work well on local machine but when hosted the pop up window appears but does not load or play the video as it should be. 
[The site hosted](https://www.liveroom.xyz/)

in the above site the product range section contains images which when clicked on will play videos on popup boxes. I have the problem with that. it works fine in http://
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have http:// references on your site and if you check your browser console, you'll see errors like the ones listed below. The non playing YouTube vidos are due to the iframe containing the YouTube URL using http instead of https (see div id=pp_full_res). Other errors like non functional Twitter links have similar causes.

Firefox:

> Blocked loading mixed active content
>   "http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js?_=1456900312321"
>
> Blocked loading mixed active content
>   "http://www.youtube.com/embed/uA2bEbabOmU?rel=1&autoplay=1"

Chrome:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.liveroom.xyz/#prettyPhoto/0/'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js?_=1456900209193'. This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>
> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.liveroom.xyz/#prettyPhoto/0/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://www.youtube.com/embed/xDXqWGoUyuw?rel=1&autoplay=1'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: I have checked the whole code but i do not have any single link calling http. everything is calling https but the console over and over shows the same error.

Comment: The link is coming from the Pretty Photo plugin js. It has hardcoded references to http (both for Twitter and Youtube). Issue was previously reported to plugin creator at https://github.com/scaron/prettyphoto/issues/157. To fix this, open jquery.prettyPhoto.js and replace all occurrences of http:// with https://

Comment: It worked. replaced all the http hardcoded parts with https.